# CI active record. get()->result() error

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

Why this code doesn't work? Error call in foreach.

```
$notifications = $this->db->select('id, shopping_region_id')
        ->from('push_notifications')
        ->where('date<=NOW()')
        ->get()->result();

    foreach ($notifications as $notification)
    {
        $test = $this->db->select('user_id, shopping_region_id')
            ->from('user')
            ->where('shopping_region_id=',$notification->shopping_region_id)
            ->get()->result();

        print_r($test);

    }
```

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on boolean in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: comment your `->where('date<=NOW()')` section and remove the `->result();` method, then `print_r($notifications)` your query, show me results that what you get ?

Comment: $notifications variable give you proper result or not

Comment: Yes, $notifications gives me a proper result.

Comment: @Frazelli can you show me the notifications result array ?

Comment: @Qazi   [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [shopping_region_id] => 38
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [shopping_region_id] => 38
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [shopping_region_id] => 38
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [shopping_region_id] => 38
        )

Comment: also tell me. when you get above proper result? after commenting the where clause ? or with where clause ?

Comment: @Qazi with where clause. I didn't comment anyting, because the first query works fine.

Comment: ->where('shopping_region_id',$notification->shopping_region_id) in foreach

Comment: @Frazelli on which `result()` you are getting error, 1st one or 2nd one which is inside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach ($notifications as $notification)
    {
        $test = $this->db->select('user_id, shopping_region_id')
            ->from('user')
            ->where('shopping_region_id' , $notification->shopping_region_id)
            ->get()->result();

        print_r($test);

    }
```